# Exception error when trying to pass down URL from a for loop into a API query

Tags: python, for-loop, python-requests

```
import requests   
import json 

api_url = "https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/%s/rate?page=1"

list =[
{"state": "Ohio", 
"state": "California",
"state": "Georgia"}
      ]  

for i in list:
   state_name = i.get("state")
   urls = api_url % state_name
print(urls) returns: >>>>> https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/Ohio/rate?page=1 https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/California/rate?page=1 https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/Georgia/rate?page=1
  
    for url in urls:
        response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "state.api+jsonv3", "Authorization": "password1234")



 Getting error message: >>>>> requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://h?
```

I'm trying to pass down the urls stored in my first for loop and pass it down to my API request. I'm fairly new to programming so any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated. I did confirm my indentation is correct in my second for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR* The reason you are getting this error is because `urls` is a string and not a list (might I suggest renaming it to `url`). This means the second for loop is unnecessary!

###### If you would like a more in depth response:

If you set the variables `urls` to a string (let's say `https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/Georgia/rate?page=1`) you don't need to iterate through it. In fact you can just pass that string to `requests.get` like so:

```py
for i in list:
   state_name = i.get("state")
   urls = api_url % state_name

   # This works fine.
   response = requests.get(urls, headers={"Accept": "state.api+jsonv3", "Authorization": "password1234"})
```

###### Now you may be wondering why you are getting the error `Invalid URL 'h': No schema supplied.`

This is because in python you *can* actually iterate through a string (which is what you are doing).

```py
for l in "https://google.com":
    print(l)
```

This will print every letter in `https://google.com` in order. So when you pass in the first letter of your URL to the requests module, it gets confused because `h` is not a URL (first letter of `https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/Georgia/rate?page=1`)

###### In conclusion

Instead of iterating through a string, you should just pass that string to `requests.get` directly

Hope this helped at least a little.

<sub><sup>This is my first stack overflow answer so any feedback is welcome!</sup></sub>

Comment: Nice answer. I'd change the variable 'list' to 'states' because list is a reserved word.

Comment: @angelacpd Yes! I was going to suggest that however it seemed relatively unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain that in such detail! :) @Funnylimericks

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop you create a variable urls which is an string and should represent a url.
After that you're doing another loop inside the first loop and in this  one you go trough every letter in this urls variabe.
The error message you get is because you try to make a request to 'h'.
Your code should look like that:

```
import requests
import json

api_url = "https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/%s/rate?page=1"

list = [
    {"state": "Ohio",
     "state": "California",
     "state": "Georgia"}
]
urls = []
for i in list:
    state_name = i.get("state")
    urls.append(api_url % state_name)
print(urls)

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "state.api+jsonv3", "Authorization": "password1234"})
```

Comment: This fixed the error! However the API query only returned the results for "Georgia" which is the last key instead of looping through all of the "state" keys. Any ideas on why this might be @dominic-nagel

Comment: I guess you're trying to access the response outside the `for url in urls` part, so the loop overrides the response every time it makes a new request. The response will be the last item which was requested. You should put the part of your code where you accessing the response inisde the loop or store all requests in a list and access it after all requests are made.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go in order.

You have created a list of one dict.
Although in your case, you need to create an array and list the necessary elements in it.

```
list =[
{"state": "Ohio", 
"state": "California",
"state": "Georgia"}
      ]
```

further in the loop, you create the urls variable, and it seems to be correct, but you redefine it. This means that if you have 100 elements, then the variable will still have the last one.

```
for i in list:
   state_name = i.get("state")
   urls = api_url % state_name
```

And since your urls is a string, then looping through it, the python will iterate each character, which is exactly what requests complain about.

Below I have attached the code which should work correctly
import requests
import json

```
api_url = "https://api.taxes.info.net/taxes/%s/rate?page=1"

states = ["Ohio", "California", "Georgia"]
request_urls = []

for state in states:
    state_name = state
    request_urls.append(api_url % state_name)

for url in request_urls:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"Accept": "state.api+jsonv3", "Authorization": "password1234"})
```

Comment: That makes sense! I tried reformatting my code to account for that and it worked, but this time it looks like the API query only returned the results for "Georgia" which is the last key. Any ideas on why this might be?